# Custom error pages in JBoss 5.0 EAP web applications

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss5.x

I'm deploying a web application and I want to have a default 404 page applicable to all my web applications unless stated otherwise in each application web.xml

I've accomplished something changing "jboss-as\server\myapp\deployers\jbossweb.deployer\web.xml" and adding the following

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error404.html</location>
</error-page>
```

Then all 404 errors I get are redirected to /error404.html without changing each application's web.xml as I wanted.

Anyway the bizarre thing is that each war I'm deploying must have a error404.html copy because it's looking for it in its own context. I tried putting error pages in jboss-as\server\myapp\deploy\ROOT.war and they work for non-defined URLs but not for already defined applications.

Can I have only one copy of my error pages for ALL contexts and that page defined only in one web.xml?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Rafa,

is "myapp" a custom profile you created? If not then try changing the file /jboss/server/all/deployers/jbossweb.deployer/web.xml.

Where "all" is one of the available jboss profiles (all, default, standard, ...).